# Was the Beis HaMakidash the central part of Judaism?

Tags: mitzvah, beis-hamikdash

Much of what "defines" Judaism now a days is of course the mitzvas that we keep and practice (aside from those connected to the Beis HaMikdash) Torah Study and Prayer. Each of these things have their set time and opportunity to perform with importance put on all them.

In the times when Beis HaMikdash stood and karbanos were brought, was this viewed as a "more important" part of Judaism and Jewish practice? While other mitzvas and Torah. Not to say that they are less important, but during those times was the Beis HaMikdash the "center or focal point" of Jewish practice where perhaps it did have "more importance".

What I'm really trying to understand is how integral having a Beis HaMikdash is to Jewish practice. Or is it simply like "any other mitzvah" (d'oraisa let's say) that is looked at in the same way.

Comment: If someone could explain the down votes that might help to improve the question...

Answer (score 0):

“The world rests upon three things, Torah, avodah (the Temple service), and gemilut hasadim (deeds of kindness).” Pirkei Avot (Ethics of the Fathers) 1:2

This would seem to imply that they are all of joint primary importance in Judaism. Prayer today comes in place of the Temple service ונשלמה פרים שפתינו "And our lips (prayer) will take the place of bulls (of the sacrifices)" (Hoshea 14:3), although of course there was always prayer alongside the sacrifices too.

Answer (score -1):

center has always been the torah. mishna in Horayot says a mamzer talmid chacham is better than a kohen gadol am haaretz.

Comment: there are many sources that discuss the advantage of Torah study which could be added to make your answer better